# Remove string that has special characters

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I have a file called `test` similar to the following:

```
hello
my
name
<h6>test morning</h6>
is
bob
```

I know I would use:

`sed -i -- 's/name//g' test`

To remove `name` from the file, but how do I remove `<h6>test morning</h6>`?

The string could be anywhere in the file and the file could be anything like a `.css` or `.html` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such cases you can use any character instead `/`. For example

```
sed -i 's|<h6>test morning</h6>||g' test
```

For string mach patterns you should escape first one

```
sed -i '\|<h6>test morning</h6>|s///g' test
```

If you have few `/` in the pattern may be easy to escape it directly

```
sed -i '/<h6>test morning<\/h6>/s///g' test
```

Comment: What do you mean 'for string match patterns'?

Comment: @Proletariat I mean pattern which used for string addressing (see example 2nd and 3rd above. FYR such variant should be quicker a little for large text)

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

In Perl, you can use a variable in the pattern part, and you can use [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta) (or the corresponding `\Q` escape) to escape special characters:

```
REPLACE='<h6>test morning</h6>' perl -pe 's/\Q$ENV{REPLACE}//'
```

Answer (score 0):

with Perl you can apply the same change for file & dir paths as well ... this code snippet turned into a bash function has been the mostly used part of code during the last 5 years both for professional and free-time projects ...

```
        # some initial checks the users should set the vars in their shells !!!
        test -z $dir_to_morph && exit 1 "You must export dir_to_morph=<<the-dir>> - it is empty !!!"
        test -d $dir_to_morph || exit 1 "The dir to morph : \"$dir_to_morph\" is not a dir !!!"
        test -z $to_srch && exit 1 "You must export to_srch=<<str-to-search-for>> - it is empty !!!"
        test -z $to_repl && exit 1 "You must export to_repl=<<str-to-replace-with>> - it is empty !!!"

        echo "INFO dir_to_morph: $dir_to_morph"
        echo "INFO to_srch:\"$to_srch\" " ;
        echo "INFO to_repl:\"$to_repl\" " ;
        sleep 2

        echo "INFO START :: search and replace in non-binary files"
        #search and replace ONLY in the txt files and omit the binary files
        while read -r file ; do (
           #debug echo doing find and replace in $file
           echo "DEBUG working on file: $file"
           echo "DEBUG searching for $to_srch , replacing with :: $to_repl"

           # we do not want to mess with out .git dir
           # or how-to check that a string contains another string
           case "$file" in
              *.git*)
              continue
              ;;
           esac
           perl -pi -e "s#\Q$to_srch\E#$to_repl#g" "$file"
        );
        done < <(find $dir_to_morph -type f -not -exec file {} \; | grep text | cut -d: -f1)

        echo "INFO STOP  :: search and replace in non-binary files"

        #search and repl %var_id% with var_id_val in deploy_tmp_dir
        echo "INFO search and replace in dir and file paths dir_to_morph:$dir_to_morph"

        # rename the dirs according to the pattern
        while read -r dir ; do (
           perl -nle '$o=$_;s#'"\Q$to_srch\E"'#'"$to_repl"'#g;$n=$_;`mkdir -p $n` ;'
        );
        done < <(find $dir_to_morph -type d|grep -v '.git')

        # rename the files according to the pattern
        while read -r file ; do (
           perl -nle '$o=$_;s#'"\Q$to_srch\E"'#'"$to_repl"'#g;$n=$_;rename($o,$n) unless -e $n ;'
        );
        done < <(find $dir_to_morph -type f -not -path "*/node_modules/*" |grep -v '.git'
```